# jquery how to write if (window.width() < 1200 && after window.resize() window.width() > 1200){}

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, width

hello i was wondering how to write this function so i could reload my page when a user resizes in those specific conditions...my ui breaks on resizes >1200px< because it uses an ajax request to load the correct navigation on page load. I want to be able to fire a reload function after the user resizes and goes from 900px to 1300px but not fire if the user were to go from 900px to 950px

thank you so much for taking the time to answer ^.^

Answer (score 0):

anyways i was able to read up on variables and how to use them with the window.width() and heres the solution:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
var $fwidth = $(window).width();

$(window).on('resize', function() {
var $nwidth = $(window).width();

if($fwidth > 1200 && $nwidth < 1200){
  location.reload();
}

if($fwidth < 1200 && $nwidth > 1200){
  location.reload();
}
});
```